# Google Web Toolkit Eclipse @Persistent(serialized ="true") Not Updating in Constructor

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing a simple Java Google Web Toolkit App, and I am having some trouble updating a variable in a class. Here is my code:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Dog implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent(serialized ="true")
    private Owner owner=null;

    public Dog() {}

    public Dog(Owner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public Owner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Where the owner class is:

```
public class Owner  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Persistent
    private String name="";

    public Owner() {}

    public Owner(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

When I run the code:

```
    Dog testDog = new Dog(new Owner("Dog Owner"));
    testDog.getOwner().getName();
```

I get an error about the owner in the dog class being null.
Why is this happening?
Why isn't the owner variable being updated in the constructor?
How do I solve this issue?

Thank you all for reading!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm just a moderator not a Java dev, but I think I may be able to help. Answer coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not a Java dev, so don't flame me if I'm totally wrong. I'm just trying to help by pointing out an inconsistency that I noticed.

In the Dog class you have

```
public Dog(Owner owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

but in Owner you have

```
public Owner(String string) {
    name = string;
}
```

I think you may be missing `this` in Owner and also in **both** your return statements.

Also, I would suggest `Owner(String name)` instead of `Owner(String string)`, but that's just me being a picky Pythonista.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I wouldn't flame you for trying to help. The reason I used this.owner in the first case is because this.owner = owner; is used when the variable names are the same so I don't think that is the case. But I defiantly should update the variable name. That's just sloppy programming.